# Challenge: maximize cost of obfuscation's reverse engineering

Tags: php, security, obfuscation

Disclaimer: Similar questions has been asked a number of times on SO, however this question is much more specific, and has not been adequately addressed so far.

We're developing a new packaged software, which, for business security reasons, must run on our customer's server, in PHP. The software is sold with a per-user end-license; price range is within $20-80 per user, target market is small (and web-savy) consultancies, and IT agencies.

To discourage piracy (eg. removing the user-license enforcement), we'd like to maximize the protection of the PHP code in any means technologically available, which does not inconvenience the user.

Let's break this down:

- does not inconvenience the user: no additional server-side installs (no zend decoder, or other binaries). Has to run on a plain-vanilla shared PHP host out-of-the-box.
- Maximize the protection: breaking the protection has to outweigh the cost of buying an additional license. That is, it has to take at least 3-5 working days for a professional hacker to remove the user license protection.
- Any means technologically available: might call home, might use high-end crypto, might implement a c64 emulator.

To pro-actively address the so far highest-voted non-solutions:

- NOT looking for *perfect* obfuscation, just *extremely hard* ones (defined as: have to take at least 3-5 working days to decrypt), OR other anti-piracy methods
- NOT looking for "black-box" software packages, which I don't know how they work, and can't determine whether it fits our purpose; looking for *algorithmic* ,and out-of-the-box ideas.
- NOT looking for license/law-side protection, we already have that covered.
- We DO know, that given enough time, and focus, all obfuscation will be hacked sooner or later; we merely want this not to be the economical solution.

Given the above constraints, what methods, or ideas would you use to maximize anti-piracy measures?

Bounty-hunt: point goes for the hardest algorithmic method to reverse-engineer the code, given the constraints above.

Update / Bounty-hunt: I've accepted Ira Baxter's answer, mostly because the rest failed to answer the core question, and attempted to question the underlying assumptions (business, closed source, yadda yadda). Thanks all!

Comment: are you discouraging privacy or piracy? theres a HUGE difference

Comment: also, talking down to potential providers of information and promising downvotes makes no friends

Comment: are the users expecting heavy use? if so, calling home would be immediately out if you want your market to expand. Otherwise your auth server might get overloaded.

Comment: Yes, but users are geographically close, and we can handle the expected call-home traffic many times over. (this doesn't mean, that I particularly like that solution, but willing to compromise, if no other means are available)

Comment: if it only takes a couple days to break, some hacker may break it for fun and make it readily available on the web for anyone who wants it. your best protection is a legal one, not a code one.

Comment: if the code base is large enough, you can probably hide something that simply registers its use in the background so you know who to litigate. never actually done anything like this though so...dunno.

Comment: As others have noted, there's no technical solution. If your product is popular, someone will crack it, and it doesn't matter how long it takes, because it only needs to be done once. But why are you worrying about this? If your product is good, people will buy it, and someone will crack it. But people will still buy it. If it's not good, then it won't be the lack of copy protection that caused it to fail. Beyond that, your target audience (businesses) are the least likely to dodge payment (e.g. compare to a video game or something). Most business don't install pirated server software.

Comment: If I wanted your software so so bad, say to resell it. I would get some cheap labour to replicate it's functionality. Haven't you ever seen the 'clone of xyz.com' ads for freelancers?

Comment: Last Comment I promise... of course unless you ask for more ;) the only way to safely protect php code is to host it yourself. Sell it as a hosted service. No-one gets to see your code so its safe. but of course I could clone your site anyway.

Comment: If the code is compiled I would not even bother implementing any obfuscation. The reason that you can open your PHP files in a text editor, goto a certain line and just comment the code or replace the code. The code does not need compilation and just scares a potential software developer who wants to make a living selling software. 

So obfuscation is needed to deter those who have the tendency of right clicking and checking how the javascript code is written and those who can read php code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to transform the code algorithmically, to obfuscate not only what is executed, but also to obfuscate the data structures.  We assume we start with a clean version of the program, produced by the developer.  He always works wih the clean version.  Obfuscation produces the to-ship version.  Good obfuscation will produce a to-ship version with exactly the same functionality as the original, so no further testing is (arguably) needed.

For control flow scrambling, the idea is to take the nicely written code you have at the start, and push it through transformations that make static (and human) analysis of the decisions that control the flow difficult by multiplying the set of assumptions that have to analyzed.  For instance, if you have two pointers, and store a value through one, can it affect the value seen by the other? Depending on whether the pointers are aliased on not, you can get two different answers.  Now take N pointers, each of which *may* be aliased; you get 2^N possible aliasing relations.  If the reader doesn't know the exact combination, he won't be able to determine if a decision might be true, false or conditional.  Of course, the tool that generates this produces conditionals whose outcome it knows, because it designs (generates) the pointer rat's nest to produce a specific outcome.

See [Code Obfuscation Literature Survey](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~arinib/writeup.pdf) (not my paper), which discusses a variety of control flow and data flow obfuscation. This is likely not the most recent summary of what is possible, but its pretty instructive.  You should note doing this kind of obfuscation has some impact on execution time.

What the papers on this topic make clear is that **control and data flow obfuscated programs are extremely hard for static analyzers to "understand"**; the papers provide/reference demonstrations of the algorithmic complexity of processing such obfuscated programs.

Now, you might argue that people aren't static analyzers and therefore don't suffer the same limitations.  You might be right; [Roger Penrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Penrose) famously argues that people do not have the same constraints as Turing machines; the argument isn't settled by a long shot.  But the entire foundation of encryption/hashing technology is built on essentially the same kind of computational complexity arguments.  And to date, nobody has proven smart enough to crack these technologies in ways
that can be used in daily life by theives (good thing, or your bank accounts would be empty).

To do this to a PHP program, you need tools that can parse the PHP code, and carry out such transformations.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has robust [PHP parsers](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/PHPFrontEnd.html), and can apply very complex transformations to code.   To do this really well, you want to apply the transformations globally across all your code, not just on a file-by-file basis.   We don't have this kind of obfuscation transformation implemented on PHP, but if you really wanted to do it, this would be the way.  We have applied complex transformations to PHP programs for other commercial products that we sell.

When you are all done, ideally you'd compile this result to machine code, say using the HipHop compiler. (Just compiling would defeat some folks, but not the serious software engineers).

EDIT: Obfuscation != AntiPiracy is a theme in other answers.  So how does obfuscation help?

First you need to deal with the anti-piracy issue.  The obvious things to do are:

- Add copyright comments to each file.  These serve as warnings to theives.  Not good ones.
- Add copyright *strings* in various places and print them out occasionally;
     these will end up in memory and play a roleif a pirate steals the code; he stole this string, too.
- Add a string to your application saying, "licensed to ".  This makes
  your customer unenthusiastic about letting it be stolen.
- Add a check to  your application that it is running on the intended customer's machine.
     (Since your app is intended to be very cheap, you'll probably need to automate
      a registration process)
- Have the application phone home with its machine ID occasionally.

Now, these steps prevent someone (legally and technically) from stealing your code.
If this is all you have, an unfazed pirate will simply remove the technical checks and its stolen.

It is very hard to prevent somebody from copying the bit stream that makes up
your product; computers are far too good at copying.
So your goal is to arrange for it to be hard for him to derive
value if he does, and that's where obfuscation comes in.

If the code is sufficiently obfuscated, he will have a difficult time locating the license check
and phone home mechansisms to disable them.  (I suggest several checks, none of them always called, to make it hard for the theif to tell when he is successful.).
The obfuscation, well done, should protect the printing of the original
owner's name, which means the original owner will have some interest in prevent it from being
stolen as you'll name him along with pirate in any lawsuit.

If they defeat the licenses, copyright printing, and phone-home mechanisms,
and simply want to run it in the back room without telling you, you might be stuck. 
(For $80.00, I can't imagine why they'd go to all this trouble just for this effect).
But many thieves want to modify the software to "improve" it, especially if they  want your market.  Serious obfuscation will prevent them for doing this; it will even
make it hard for them to add thier own license controls.
That limits the value pretty severely.

They may simply steal it and release it to world for free; your hope here is
the applicaton is hard to crack.   If they succeed, your only good defense
 is a continuing stream of upgrades that licensed owners get.

Obfuscation is a key to successful piracy defense, IMHO.

Comment: Wow, okay, this is the closest we have so far. Can you elaborate on the implementation details of pointer-based control flow-rewriting in PHP?

Comment: @Silver Dragon (580 chars of elaboration).  The obfuscator needs to manufacture a largish data structure this is effectively full of pointers (you can simulate with with an array using indexes), in which it knows the answers to the questions of @p==q or a[i]==j by construction, for every value p,q or i,j.  Then it modifies each test of the original code  if (t)  to be if (t && a[e1]==e2) for some values of e1 and e2 it can compute from the context around the if statement.  Of course, the obfuscator knows the outcome of this test, but a person/tool reading the code cannot.

Comment: @Silver Dragon ... that is only the very simplest characterization of what to do; one can flatten the control flow, too, so the order of execution of the if statements are completely unobvious.  All this needs a strong program transformation system such as DMS.

Comment: obfuscation only helps you feel better. It only needs to be de-obfuscated once, if at all. Phone home can be solved by a simple search no matter how obfuscated. If the software runs as is why even bother to de-obfuscate it. just run it! To break the phone home without even touching the code, simply add the phone home domain to the hosts file with an invalid ip or block the ip with a firewall if the ip is hard coded. I can do both within five minutes of installing the software.

Comment: @DeveloperChris: for the kind of obfuscation being discussed here, which requires the ability to analyze a Turing machine, your remark is rather like, "Your password only has to be decrypted once". True, but with modern encryption technology, that's pretty hard. If you don't think so, there's a world of banks out there just waiting for you to empty their vaults. You can kill the phone home by preventing it from phoning, but if the software's response is to quit running then you are dead unless you disable the phone home logic. That requires you to solve the obfuscation problem. Oops.

Comment: @Ira. This is not encryption we are speaking about. This is obfuscation. The php interpreter must be able to interpret it (or run the pre-compiled code). So it just looks ugly and incomprehensible to a human. That's it nothing more. Stopping phone home is so dead easy its not worth even thinking about. pre-compiled code (byte code) can be easily decompiled. but I wouldn't even bother I'd just run it and prevent phone home. also you failed to mention hiphop compiled code can't be safely run on different platforms it must be compiled on the target machine. so the end user needs the source code!

Comment: @DeveloperChris: Check out this paper, too: Limits of static analysis for malware detection - Moser,  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.131.784&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @Ira Phone home is more effective if it runs every time and keyed to the machine, but if your customer is behind a natted firewall or load balancer that is very hard. If it runs every time then you are at the mercy of the sellers server, if its slow the script is slow. And no matter how obfuscated it is it can be reverse engineered, Visually it may look like a mess. But to a cpu its just a set of instructions. you must also consider the extra cpu load of all those extra lookups and conversions. If the software has any real value it will end up on a torrent.

Comment: I glanced through those papers, the first relates more to compilable languages such as c++, many of the techniques are not applicable such as hiding code in the 'text' section the second paper referred to fooling signature based antivirus tools, not preventing decompilation thru obfuscation. I spent many months creating encryption techniques to prevent pirating of a heavily pirated piece of software, in the end I succeeded. If I had spent the time and effort on improving the software instead, I would have earned 10x the amount I though I had lost. it was a fools victory.

Comment: @DeveloporChris: Both papers are clear that one can scramble control and data flow to the point that a static analysis tool is hopelessly confounded. People are arguably smarter, but hard is still hard. The technique isn't special with respect to the language. (Yes, the 2nd paper talks about a bunch of object code tricks but they aren't relevant here; the rest of it is). I think you'e made your point: you don't believe, and you don't believe it is worth the effort. Others are welcome to judge the evidence on the face of it. Finally, OP asked for what was possible; I believe this is it.

Answer (score 7):

`Obfuscation != Anti-piracy` For instance you could have a heavily obfuscated class,  but I can use reflection to see all methods that this class implements.  I can then extend this class and override any methods that I don't like.  Are you storing a secret?  Because any secret value can be pulled from memory using a debugger.

3-5 days?  Even with Zend-Guard it takes 3-5 seconds to break using some open source tool.  Most obfuscation tools are very primitive and easy to break.

I'm sorry but I don't think there is a good solution for this.

Comment: Zend guard is a well-known problem -with well-known solutions; this is the reason why I'm looking for algorithmic solutions -so it would need a specialist for effective code breaking.

Comment: >  Obfuscation != Anti-piracy   -in that case, what methods would you recommend for anti-piracy measures?

Comment: @Silver Dragon okay i'll bite.  Don't distribute the code.  Change your business model and adopt software as a service.   I honestly believe that this is impossible, just look at all the cracked software being distributed via p2p.

Comment: With heavily obfuscated code, you can see which methods implement a class merely by inspecting the code; who needs reflection? It still says CLASS AZ23324 { METHOD X82348 { } METHOD F23843 { } } . And yes, you can even extend that class! In fact, you can see *all* the code and modify any piece of it. The real question is, will you have any idea what you are doing? How will you know you don't like a method? If you don't understand the code, no change you will make will have any serious chance of working.

Comment: Yes, most "obfuscators" that actually encrypt are easy to break; the shipped encrypted program has to contain the decryptor and thus the key to its direct decoding. The Zend product can compile to PHP byte code, and now you to reverse engineer to get code structure; maybe your reflection stunt might be faintly useful in this case. Real obfuscators that obfuscate weakly (name substition only) or strongly (see my answer) put the theif into a reverse engineering problem. If it is harder than the value to the thief, you've won.

Comment: @Ira Baxter You missed my point,  perhaps you should visit thepiratebay.org sometime.

Comment: @Rook: I know about Pirate Bay. Yes, there are enthusiastic hackers out there. The question was can you defend reasonably against them? And yes, they have a lot of stuff, much of it music and movies which can't be "obfuscated" (who would watch Harry Potter if all the pixels were rearranged?) but are encrypted or play-disabled by a single key scheme; a single point of failure. Much of the software was likely protected, if at all, with simple checks; eseentially single points of failure. ...

Comment: @Rook: Obfuscated code done well is obfuscated everywhere.  To change it, you have to change all the places that give you a bad time; if you fail at one, you've failed.  So it doesn't have the single point of failure problem.  And it is a different kind of problem than disabling a key; it turns the cracking problem into an *understanding* problem.  Real programs are already hard to understand.  Obfuscated ones are much worse.  Can you show an formerly obfuscated program present at Pirate Bay, which is easy to modify and enhance?

Comment: @Ira Baxter So your argument is either that your method of anti-piracy is much better than that used by the latest games,  or that your software isn't valuable enough to pirate.  If its not valuable enough to pirate then its not valuable enough to write in the first place.  Anti-piracy can never work it is by definition "in-security though obscurity".  I prefer to concern my self with solvable problems in security.

Comment: @Rook: Data encryption techniques are designed to be hard to crack because there are few clues on how to find the keys. They lean on the intellectual/mathematical toughness of factoring, packing bins, etc. You seem to be willing to believe in those (your login passwords *are* encrypted, right?). Obscurity used the way you have used is pejorative; you're assuming "easy to crack". Strong obfuscation as described in my answer (and the papers that back it up) is intellectually/mathematically hard to crack (see the theorems) in the same kind of way that encyption schemes are.

Comment: @Ira Baxter Passwords **must never** be encrypted,  that would be a violation of CWE-257.  The rest of you are describing is not a secure system.  Please read up on "Security though obscurity", it is universally looked down upon.

Comment: @Rook: OK, I simplified my argument because I only had 500 characters and other things to say. "Use one way hashing and salt". If you examine this, we're back to "hard to crack because of intellectual/mathematical" limitations. That doesn't change my argument: we are talking about security through mathematically demonstrated difficulty.  Your phrase, "Security through obscurity" seems aimed at weak methods of hiding the gold, and everybody agrees "weak is weak defense".   We're talking about mathematically strong methods.

Comment: @Ira Baxter And thats where I disagree,  because DRM is a joke.  If you think your right,  call up Sony and tell them you solved the problem of piracy.

Comment: @Rook: I don't think you are hearing my point. DRM is a single point of failure scheme; it attempted to protect vast amounts of IP using *one* trick that didn't depend on the content strongly. Strong obfuscation defends individual programs in ways that depend on the code in the individual program; cracking one doesn't help you with the next. Nor is it crack it once, and you've cracked the whole thing; it is crack each individual piece you need to modify (including figuring where that piece is). And the financial reward is "crack this one program" as opposed to "crack the movie industry".

Comment: @Ira Baxter It is baffling why you keep brining up movies.  I'm talking about the sony PlayStation 3 hack which is a good example because it took a few years to break.  Millions of dollars are spent trying to prevent piracy and every single attempt has failed miserably.  Do you really think you have the solution?

Comment: @Rook: So Sony delivered something that took a few years to break by a pretty determined set of hackers. For Sony, this is a catastrophic failure; they can't recall the PS3s and change the protection.   If you can get a few years of protection for a particular version of the program, and can ship another version with new feature in the meantime, even a successful pirate has won a Phyrric victory.  Nobody wants to run Windows 98 anymore, having been supplanted by Windows7.

Comment: @Ira Baxter There will never be a solution to piracy and obfuscation is laughable.   Please please please please please read wikipedia page on "Security though obscurity".  I'm sorry but I only see someone who very confused on what the meaning of security is.   This conversation is over.

Comment: @Rook: Your last statement is not a reasoned argument. I can understand it is your opinion.  I will honor your request and read that page carefully.  If it changes my opinion, I'll say so here.

Comment: @Rook... so I did. To quote: "Security through ... obscurity is ... referring to a principle in security engineering, which attempts to use secrecy (of design, implementation, etc.) to provide security. A system relying on security through obscurity may have theoretical or actual security vulnerabilities, but its owners or designers believe that the flaws are not known, and that attackers are unlikely to find them." What part of the scheme I am advocating is secret?

Comment: @Ira Baxter The code its self or method you are employing to prevent the application from running on multiple machines.

Comment: @Rook: No more so than that encrypted value you store that you think is hard to decrypt. I agree, we don't see the world the same way. Each of us makes a bet. You've made yours, based on what I think of as people attacking weak schemes. I have an optimistic view for mine based on complexity theory, which has been pretty effective at telling us what is computationally hard. We'll see which one works out.

Comment: @Ira Baxter cool man i'm going to go play my pirated copy of Crysis 2.  Have a good day.

Answer (score 6):

The best anti piracy method is no method.

If you don't want to use tools such as zend, then you are better off doing absolutely nothing.

Take it from me you can waste more time and lose sales trying to stop pirates. you will only hurt yourself. Hey they don't care and its good fun, the harder you make it the more satisfaction they get in doing it. and once its done it will be available for all via a torrent. so no-one needs to repeat the effort.

Make a good application. make it work well. give Fantastic service and the customers you want will gladly pay. those customers you don't want will NEVER pay so don't waste time on them. And guess what, they actually become good advertising. people see your software on more sites they come looking for it.

So in effect you are getting free advertising.

So don't stress, don't waste your time and don't blame pirates if your software fails. blame yourself because you got too distracted trying to do the impossible

I wanted to add a little bit of my personal experience.

Back in the 90's I spent many months creating encryption techniques to reduce/prevent pirating of a heavily pirated piece of software, in the end I 'mostly' succeeded.

I used custom encryption, junk insertion, random number generators, cross module CRC checking, blah blah blah.

I used to hang out in the news group devoted to hacking my software and others like it and even struck up conversations. one polite fellow said "why are you wasting your time we do this for fun". but I was hooked. it was a competition.

If I had spent the time and effort on improving the software instead, I would have earned 10x the amount I thought I had lost to piracy.

It was a fools victory.

Comment: +1 Amen to that. However, with some extension this can turn into a debate about software business practices and open source business models; I'm afraid this is not what the OP is interested in. Hopefully though this will hit a chord that will resonate..

Comment: +1 I would even add that you licence as GPL to avoid others cracking and building on top of your effort without releasing source that you can use. The key is the service, not the software.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2):

I thought about this a lot, and what you are asking is essentially impossible. You can obfuscate to no end and people will still steal your software. There is little you can do about it. If you write in code to call home, someone will strip it out and just put `true` in instead. Your best bet is to write quality software so people want to buy it. It's either that or use a commercial solution like ionCube or Zend.

Comment: In that case, what does "commercial solution like ionCube, or Zend" do?  (see blackbox argument above about "not knowing != security")

Comment: Half of what Zend does is symbol-for-symbol substition, which is weak obfuscation (same level of protection as a front door lock).  That's OK against most PHP-based opponents.

Comment: so even the commercial solution uses weak protection. You just helped make my point, actually. My main point was to focus on the quality of the software, not the obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Only a few things can really work. The most basic logic I can think of that would be effective (since this market sounds like it's fairly controlled, and finite) would be to use something similar to a licensing server, but with a two-way communication channel (that you can encrypt etc.. etc..).

Now, of course you can have someone disable that communication channel, but between the coding you will add to disable the software, and the fact that your company will be able to follow up with the client since you will know exactly who it is that is "down" that will help.

The third part of the logic, is for each license that is given out to play a role in generating the "checks" that will occur between the software and your licensing server. This means you generate, on-premise, unique hash codes that are used as part of the answer your software send back to the server. That pretty much rules out the hacking, because the hacker would have to know what algorith you are using to generate the licensing (since it is pre-generated, there is no logic to use to decipher it) and the hacker would have to feed you a licensing key.

The fourth step, optionally, would be to push updates to clients to refresh the security mechanisms you have in place and run "tamper" checks on your code, possibly periodically feed some sort of hash to be used in the logic your software uses to connect to the licensing server.

This still isn't perfect, someone "will" be able to clone a production machine, circumvent/redirect the licensing (and you won't know since it will be a copy) and try to work away at the check that you have in your code which require a license (as someone above mentioned, set all the logic to "True")... but you could definitly spend the time putting checks and encryption on your licensing system and make it a time-consuming and "risky" process. Unlesss.. as a final touch... you can have some deliverable from your product generated by your server (none of the code is in what the client has) and pushed to the software that has this licensing mechanism in place.. but i don't know how possible that is.

Answer (score 0):

**Artificial code bloat**

By using post processors to automatically bloat the code and insert logic multipliers you make the code hard to modify

I use tags in the original source to indicate the type of code in each method and which code multiplier to use. Randomisers can help too, as each release looks very different

The code bloat is achieved by a variety of processes. e.g. repeating and random fiddling of variables before and after they are officially in scope. Lots of extra logic steps that will never get followed. Breaking single statements into many random small steps. Interlace these with as many other statements as possible as long as the final step is in the correct order. etc etc

The **final and most important** part of this process is to interlace key generation and call home processes through this mess, and to be part of this mess (remember the "random fiddling of variables before and after they are officially in scope") so that the time taken to remove the key generation and call home become unwieldy

The call home server has to act like a [rolling code remote control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_code) so while the attacker might discover the call home functions, taking them out will result in incorrect initialisation values for general variables in general methods, and in as many cases as you can work with

Over time you can build the general purpose code re-parser, and a library of functions to mess the code up. Keep adding the code mess library to improve the obfuscation level

You need to have a well covering unit and integration test library to validate the code after being messed up

I have not done this with PHP, but with other languages with similar constraints as PHP

**Note:** This technique works fine for complex scientific software where there is large amounts of cryptic logic and maths anyway. It may not work so well for typical web sites like CMS's unless your code multipliers are very convincing

Comment: The biggest problem here is "library of functions to mess the code up". To do this reliably for a language, either you have make some very hard rules about where it is allowed to mess, so it doesn't have to be smart about the parsing/understanding the code, or you have to have sophisticated machinery that understands the code at the same level as a compiler, so it can make a mess by intervening in the real code without breaking it.  If you play the hard-rule game, your obfuscated code will likely act like dead code, and is easily eliminated by a serious opponent.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, why not invest in a server to be delivered within the cost of the application, a server which can be placed at the customer, with only one port opened for http access, I mean with a $1000 you can get a machine that can work as a safe for your software. If anyone attempts to hack into it you will know.

Another solution might be:

Currently I am working for a huge company that has aprox 350 selling points(shops) all over the country. As we can not rely on internet connection 100% we have a server at each shop. This server handles the business required for actual selling and it is linked to a local database. The rest of the stuff sits at the head-office server. Now, the clerks have computers in front of them, and all these computers work with the application hosted on the local server, the catch on the local server is that a registry which knows if a certain service is placed locally (on the same machine) or remote (at the head office) and executes the call as required (over http from remote location or direct call from local service). Services can be placed anywhere (local or remote) and all one needs to do is to configure their location in the registry by simply entering one of the keywords : local,remote,application (application keyword means that the service is first called from remote and if it fails it is called locally). This way you can make an acceptable compromise. Highly necessary stuff can sit locally and the rest of the business logic can reside on your server where nobody can touch it.

Comment: 2nd paragraph above: $20-$80 price range per user X small consultancies / companies (5-20 users) -> max margin per company is in the range of $1000-1800; dedicated hw deployment cost: $1000 + maintenance + shipping & operation cost + customer inconvenience => would eat into our margins massively. So: nice try, but no cigar :)

Comment: how about the 50/50 appoach I've told you about :)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is no way to obfuscate code in such a complex manner that it takes **days** to crack. The simple explanation: obfuscation is a two way process. It can be done and undone. If a computer can do it, a determined person can do it too.
Instead of wasting so much time on protecting your code, why not take the hint from the popular TV show 24 (side note: Should have never been canceled!). To ensure scripts weren't stolen or revealed to the public, they watermarked each with a number specific to cast member, director, producer, etc. You can do something similar with you scripts by "watermarking" each PHP file. This can be something as simple as changing the name of the variable to reflect a client ID or something as complex as spreading identifying characters over multiple variable and function values/names. Try working this identifier and/or parts of it into as many inconspicuous places in your scripts as possible.  Only you can know the exact combination that creates the identifying information. This way if code is leaked you can sue the responsible party.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I'm not sure you read my answer carefully.  The scheme outlined depends on fundamental algorithmic complexity of the hard kind.

Comment: With the computing power available today, the algorithm would have to be insanely complicated to take days to crack. And in theory, if it took days to crack it would also take the server that executed the code days to run, so the server executing the code would have to be exponentially faster than a hacker's computer (which will not always be possible). Again though, this is all just theory.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: Any algorithn that requires exponential effort to crack can stop any supercomputer you can name for centuries.  If you have to try 2^64 combinations at the rate of 1 per nanosecond, you will need 2^33 seconds to have a 50% chance of cracking it.  That's 272 years.   Complexity theory says some things are computationally very hard to do, and even today's fast computers can't do them.    No, the running application doesn't have to crack anything; it *knows* the answer already.  Read the papers I cite carefully.

Comment: @Ira I'll give them a look. Just to play devil's advocate: if the running application already "knows the answer" then wouldn't cracking the application's code be as simple as gaining physical access to the server and grabbing the already compiled and unencrypted PHP script from the server's RAM? Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but I just don't see any solution that's perfectly fool-proof.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: You are using hte word "unencrypt".  Souorce code *obfuscation* does not encrypt the code; it scrambles the code in a way that makes it computationally infeasible for an analyzer program to make any predictions about sequence of executions, and thus about content of variables and thus about purpose.  The scrmabled code executes directly on the server; no unscramblilng necessary.  The scrambled code could be stolen directly, but it will remain scrambled.  Thus its last defense is to make sure it is running where it expects to run, defeating the pirates theft.

Comment: @Ira I understand, but couldn't some of the obfuscation be removed by examining the source that is compiled by PHP? It might not be enough to be readable but I'd say it would be a start. This is sort of similar to how minifying JavaScript makes it very difficult to read!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I don't think you've read the technical papers carefully.  This has nothing to do with compiling the code; the assumption is that you have the obfuscated source code in your hands.

Answer (score -2):

Just a suggestion, you might just want to add needed lines of code that don't really do anything, except it looks like it.